# custom ServerAuthModule (loginModule), where to hash the password? JASPIC

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jaspic

I'm trying to implement a loginmodule so I can perform a "remember me" feature on my web app as well as hash my password with bcrypt. To build the class I used [this tutorial](http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2015/01/using-jaspic-to-secure-web-application.html). However I didn't manage to connect after implementing this. The passwords in db are hashed via SHA-256 at the moment and I suspect it is the reason why.

```
  public class TestAuthModule implements
        javax.security.auth.message.module.ServerAuthModule {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected static final Class[] supportedMessageTypes = new Class[] {
            HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class };

    private CallbackHandler handler;

    public void initialize(MessagePolicy requestPolicy,
            MessagePolicy responsePolicy, CallbackHandler handler,
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map options) throws AuthException {
        System.out.println("initialize called.");
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Class[] getSupportedMessageTypes() {
        return supportedMessageTypes;
    }

    public AuthStatus validateRequest(MessageInfo messageInfo,
            Subject clientSubject, Subject serverSubject) throws AuthException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) messageInfo
                .getRequestMessage();

        String user = request.getParameter("user");
        String group = request.getParameter("group");

        System.out.println("validateRequest called.");
        System.out.println("User = " + user);
        System.out.println("Group = " + group);

        authenticateUser(user, group, clientSubject, serverSubject);

        return AuthStatus.SUCCESS;
    }

    public AuthStatus secureResponse(MessageInfo msgInfo, Subject service)
            throws AuthException {
        System.out.println("secureResponse called.");
        return AuthStatus.SEND_SUCCESS;
    }

    public void cleanSubject(MessageInfo msgInfo, Subject subject)
            throws AuthException {
        if (subject != null) {
            subject.getPrincipals().clear();
        }
    }

    private void authenticateUser(String user, String group,
            Subject clientSubject, Subject serverSubject) {
        System.out
                .println("Authenticating user " + user + " in group " + group);

        CallerPrincipalCallback callerPrincipalCallback = new CallerPrincipalCallback(
                clientSubject, user);

        GroupPrincipalCallback groupPrincipalCallback = new GroupPrincipalCallback(
                clientSubject, new String[] { group });

        try {
            handler.handle(new Callback[] { callerPrincipalCallback,
                    groupPrincipalCallback });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and I login like this (which did work before implementing a custom loginmodule):

```
private String username;
private Password password;
//....

for (int i = 0; i < x -1 ; i++) {
    this.password = PasswordEncoder
                       .toHex(PasswordEncoder
                            .hash512(this.password + salt));
    }
   // x is the number of time I hashed the password before storing it in db.
   // x-1 because glassfish authentication does it once for me.

   //...
try {
    request.login(username, password + salt);
    } catch (ServletException e)
```

Also on my pages I used to have a register and a sign in button that were displayed only if the user was null if not I had the username at the top. Now that I implemented this it's like the user is connected as "ANONYMOUS" (so there is "you are connected as ANONYMOUS" at the top of the page.
To prevent this I did a temporary fix:

```
    if (username == null || username.equals("ANONYMOUS")) {
        this.isUserConnected = false;
    } else {
        this.isUserConnected = true;
    }
```

I tried :

```
isUserInGroup("ANONYMOUS");
```

but there is no user so I'm getting a npe. I'm not sure how to go about this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two alternative approaches you can employ here.

The first --which I personally favor-- would be to just forget about proprietary AS-provided JAAS `LoginModule`s (LMs) altogether and implement the authentication process in its entirety yourself, within your `ServerAuthModule`'s (SAM's) `validateRequest` method. This gives you the ultimate freedom of choice with regard to how credentials are to be persisted (hashing/salting, DB schema) by the application and how the SAM shall perform validation of client-supplied credentials. Hence, the SAM is responsible for connecting to the DB in both a thread-safe and efficient manner in that case; that would be the sole potentially tricky aspect of this approach.

Alternatively, your SAM can delegate credential validation to an AS-provided LM (or to one you authored, provided that it is applicable, i.e. a vendor-specific extension). That's what you've been trying to accomplish, I suppose. The SAM must then comply with both JASPIC's *Servlet Container Profile* and its *LoginModule Bridge Profile* (see chapter 6 of the spec); the latter, in a nutshell, mandates that:

1. The SAM's `initialize` method consults the value of the `javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext` key encapsulated within the runtime-provided `options`. It also constructs an *additional* `CallbackHandler` that supports `NameCallback` and `PasswordValidationCallback`. Finally, it instantiates a request-specific `LoginContext` (LC) with the aforementioned instances (`name` and `callbackHandler` arguments, respectively).
2. Its `validateRequest` delegates to LC's `login`; then communicates any `Principal`(s) established by the underlying LM within LC's `Subject` to the AS (via `CallerPrincipalCallback` and `GroupPrincipalCallback`).
3. Its `cleanSubject` delegates to LC's `logout`.

Obviously, unless you wrote the LM yourself, no clean way of altering the credential validation process is available.

Some closing notes:

- `HttpServletRequest.login` will always raise an exception when JASPIC has been configured for use with your application (see § 3.9.2 of the spec). Use `HttpServletRequest.authenticate` instead.
- Your SAM's `validateRequest` should return a proper `AuthStatus`; namely `SUCCESS` when login succeeded or authentication is *optional* (i.e. the requested resource is unprotected), regardless of the authentication outcome; `SEND_CONTINUE` when redirecting the user to a login page; `SEND_FAILURE` (or throw an `AuthException`) when login failed and authentication is *mandatory* (i.e. the requested resource is protected or the user explicitly requested to be logged in).
- The identity of the unauthenticated user should be communicated by your SAM's `validateRequest` to the AS by supplying the `CallerPrincipalCallback`/`GroupPrincipalCallback` constructor with a `null` *principal* or *groups* argument, respectively. A compatible Servlet container's `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal`'s implementation should then return `null`. Note that `EJBContext.getCallerPrincipal` behaves differently, returning an instance of an AS-specific type in order to represent the unauthenticated user (perhaps that's what you witnessed). In any case, your authorization-related application-level code should not depend on the non-standard name of the anonymous `Principal`. An alternative way of addressing the *is-guest* question could involve setting the `javax.servlet.http.authType` callback property (see § 3.8.4 of the spec) from your SAM on successful authentication. Invoking `HttpServletRequest.getAuthType` would then not only assert whether the user is authenticated, but also whether your SAM, another SAM or AS-specific LM performed the authentication (think of an app leveraging multiple authentication types). Yet another way of dealing with this could be by passing a custom `Principal` implementation to the `CallerPrincipalCallback`; then doing an `instanceof` on the `Principal` exposed via `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal` (but note that there are still issues, e.g. on [GlassFish](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16587) an EJB is needed to achieve the same result).

See also:

- [JSR-196 1.1 MR 2](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaspic-1_1-mrel2-eval-spec/)
- [Sample use of the JASPIC's LoginModule Bridge Profile](https://blogs.oracle.com/nasradu8/entry/loginmodule_bridge_profile_jaspic_in)